# Odoo: how to have one calendar with all events (meetings, calls, projects tasks)

Tags: odoo

In my company we planned to use a new tools to manage all our projects, calls, meetings, sales etc

Odoo seems to be a good choice but we have a big limitation: each tools (Project, CRM) use its own calendar.

How can we planned a task, a call or a meeting if we do not have a complete view of events ?

My question is how can we do this (I have search and it seems to be impossible)

How are we suppose to use a calendar to planning events ? (maybe our approach is wrong ...)

Comment: Technically speaking, calendar is just a type view in Odoo. Every object (project, meeting, sale, etc) could have their own calendar view but they can not to be mixed in one calendar view.